# How to handle Audio Mute on a crossplatform agora app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have a cross platform agora app. The Mobile version is using the Agora React Native SDK while the web version is using the Web SDK v4. When I was implementing the audio mute / unmute indication I found that the event does not trigger from mobile to web. Can anyone please help me with this, what should I do to make it work?

```
// This is the Code From React Native 
    const toggleAudio = useCallback(async () => {
    await RtcEngine.instance().enableLocalAudio(!audioEnabled);

    setCurrentUser(prev => {
        return { ...prev, audioEnabled: !audioEnabled }
    })
    setAudioEnabled(!audioEnabled);
}, [audioEnabled]);
```

And Here is the Web event Handler

```
 client.on("user-unpublished", (user, type) => {
            if (type === "audio") {
                user.audioTrack?.stop();
                setRemoteUsers(prev => {
                    return prev.map(ussr => ussr.uid == user.uid ? user : ussr);
                })
            }

            if (type == 'video') {
                setRemoteUsers(prev => {
                    return prev.map(ussr => ussr.uid == user.uid ? user : ussr);
                })
            }
        });
```

The handler works for web to web and also for the video event on mobile but doesn't trigger the callback for the audio

Answer (score 0):

On the react-native app use the [muteLocalAudioStream](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/react_native/classes/rtcengine.html#mutelocalaudiostream) method instead.